# How to count the number of list items that are dynamically added to a page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to count the number of list items on a page which are added dynamically using jQuery. I know how to count them when they are already on the page. But, how do I do it when list items are being added dynamically?

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="working">Lorem 1</li>
  <li class="working">Lorem 2</li>
  <li class="working">Lorem 3</li>
  <li class="working">Lorem 4</li>
  <li class="working">Lorem 5</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('li.working').length > 2) {
        alert('More than 2');
    }
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzn1o97j/) that counts static number of list items. Can somebody please help me **count the number of list items when they are added dynamically on the page?**

Comment: It will be counted in the same way. What is the challenge you are facing?

Comment: Check `$('li.working').length` after you append...Makes sense ?

Comment: Else, after you append `li` to the `ul` call the function which will iterate through the ul elements via `each` function

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r3aj42rg/

Comment: Check this - https://jsfiddle.net/uj26vte6/

Answer (score 2):

Use the below HTML :

```
<button>Click to add li</button>
<p>No. of list items : <span></span></p>
<ul></ul>
```

And Below is the jquery code to add list-items dynamically and display the list-items count value :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var c=1;
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('ul').append("<li class='working'>Lorem "+c+"</li>");
    c++;
    $('p span').text($('li.working').length);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to know the length after you add the list dynamically via jquery. You can just count the length after the successful append of list. I have created a dummy append with button(you can do it however you prefer).
HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="working">Lorem 1</li>
  <li class="working">Lorem 2</li>
  <li class="working">Lorem 3</li>
  <li class="working">Lorem 4</li>
  <li class="working">Lorem 5</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $( "#add" ).on( "click", function() {
    var size = $('ul').find('li').length;
    $('ul').append('<li class="working">Lorem '+(size+1)+'</li>');

    //replica of the ajax dynamic addition. Just check for the length after successful append in you UI
    $( "ul" ).promise().done(function() {
   if($('li.working').length > 2) {
    alert($('li.working').length);
  }
  });
    });

});
```

Here is the FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/rumba_alex47/1mmokwvf/

Answer (score 0):

Please find the [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/3hyt9mjk/1/).

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="working">Lorem 1</li>
    <li class="working">Lorem 2</li>
    <li class="working">Lorem 3</li>
    <li class="working">Lorem 4</li>
    <li class="working">Lorem 5</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="add()">
    ADD
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function add() {
    $('ul').append('<li class="working">Lorem ' + ($('ul li.working').length + 1) + '</li>');
}
```